# squid external acl authentication

Tags: squid

I setup a proxy machine (centOS) and I'm using Squid. I have php external ACL program that will handle proxy authentication.

On my external program (php cli) I have included a small logic that will remember a user's log-in. My goal is the piece of information i collected in external acl can be used in my redirector external program so i can redirect the user to a page i set-up (A message of a day page). and after redirecting to a page i just simply reset the flag.

My problem is this; the external acl is not always triggered by Squid during the Ident authentication process when we have same username/password entered. Unless I restart the Squid. Calling always the external acl during the proxy authentication process is important to me because I want the logic inside my external acl is also executed during the proxy authentication.

Is there any setting in the squid.conf to be configure so that it will behave as I want?

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding properly that you're expecting every incoming HTTP request to trigger a call to your acl helper, saving the credentials in the helper instead of using squid's internal auth cache? If so, add ttl=0 to the external_acl_type argument.

Comment: hi caw, thanks for your reply. well, not really every incoming http request nor saving cached on helper but every proxy authentication only my external acl will be triggered. Is that possible?